# Uncheck radio button in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I have a questionnaire with several radio buttons like this:

```
<mat-radio-group name="questionA" [(ngModel)]="model.questionA">
 <mat-radio-button *ngFor="let ans of answers" [value]="ans.value">
   {{ans.display}}
 </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

What I want is to be able to uncheck the selected radio when I make a click in it.

I have tried this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap4-rpslys that I've forked from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55005641/how-to-uncheck-a-radio-button-on-its-second-click-angular-2). But I can't make it work in my case.

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: why would you want to deselect a radio button group?? add a `None` option instead

Comment: Is a client request, good sir.

Comment: I think that's not the way radio-buttons are intended in HTML standards  read further here `https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13511/why-is-it-impossible-to-deselect-html-radio-inputs`. Also I would prefer to use a dropdown instead of radio button as it is more extendable

Comment: Yes, I know, but: questions must be radio buttons, you should de able to "uncheck" them. Nothing I can do except fulfill the request.

Comment: mat-radio-button do not provide api to uncheck radio button, but you can find answer of your solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53612626/angular-material-mat-radio-button-unchecked-on-multiple-click

Comment: @DoTrungDuc yeah, that answer was what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the element reference on mat-radio-button and unselect the radio button
in the ts file and you need to pass this #element reference to click event and apply changes in type script file.

```
<mat-radio-group name="questionA" [(ngModel)]="model.questionA" (click)="func(element)">
 <mat-radio-button #element *ngFor="let ans of answers" [value]="ans.value">
   {{ans.display}}
 </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

```
//Inside function in .ts file
fun(element){
//some code
element.checked = false;
}
```

Hope this helps.